# Toggle hidden columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Given an excelsheet with e.g. 5 hidden columns I can select the complete sheet and press Ctrl+Shift+8 to unhide the columns (at least that's the combination on a german excel).

Well, now I can view all the data and make my changes.

Later on I want to hide again exactly those columns, that I just unhided. Is that possible without plugins? Note that I can't use undo, as I did other changes to the worksheet since unhiding the columns.

I am using the latest Excel from Office 365.

Comment: At the top left of the sheet with hidden column is "1"  "2"  and maybe more.. "1" hides all columns, "2" unhides all columns.  Can you use that?   I do this.

Comment: Does "Select columns > r-click > Hide " work ?